# Rvest works fine locally but the same code crashes when Shiny app deployed

Tags: r, shiny, rvest

So I have a Shiny app that does the following:

1) User enters a link for a specific type of craigslist page and clicks "Go".

2) App validates the the link is in the approved format.

3) If not of approved format, an error message pops up. User must try again.

4) If the link is in the approved format, a conditional panel displays and it shows an html widget loader until a table with the data from their craigslist page appears.

5) The table then appears.

**ISSUE:** When I run the app locally, everything works perfectly. Invalid inputs are caught, the conditional panel displays if a valid link was entered, data is scraped, and the user can repeat the process again and again. BUT, when I run it on a live Shiny server, the app crashes.

**THINGS I'VE TRIED**
I started with the traditional read_html() from rvest and it does not work on a live server. App crashes. Data is "not found."

I have tried downloading the html page for the site and storing it in the wd of the app, then have the app pull it back in with read_html() and it does not work. Data is "not found". Still works locally.

I have tried removing the validation checks on the link to see if that was causing the error. This does not fix it (still works locally).

I have tried removing the conditional panel in case the display logic was broken. That does not fix it (still works locally).

**CODE**

This is the code I am using to scrape. I am looping over many pages of craigslist listings as you can see.

```
pageScraper <- function(url){

    print("Entered print loop")
    Listings <- c("1")
    Links <- c("1")
    totalListingsDataFrame <- data.frame(Listings,Links)
    colnames(totalListingsDataFrame) <- c("Listings","Links")

    keepRunning <- TRUE

    while(keepRunning){

      #Read web page as HTML
      #download.file(url, destfile = "scrapedpage.html", quiet=TRUE)
      webPage <- read_html(url)

      #Scrape all of the listing names & store as 1-column data frame
      scrapedListings <- webPage %>% html_nodes(".hdrlnk") %>% html_text()
      #Get all links for posts
      scrapedLinks <- webPage %>% html_nodes(".hdrlnk") %>% html_attr("href")

      #Put listings and links into data frame
      scrapedData <- data.frame(scrapedListings,scrapedLinks)
      colnames(scrapedData) <- c("Listings","Links")
      #Bind new data to master data frame
      totalListingsDataFrame <- rbind(totalListingsDataFrame,scrapedData)

      #Generate new link stub for next page
      nextLink <- webPage %>% html_node(".next") %>% html_attr("href")
      if(is.na(nextLink) || nextLink == ""){
        break
      }
      #Create full link for next page
      newPage <- gsub("(/search/).*",nextLink,url)
      url <- newPage
    }

    totalListingsDataFrame <- totalListingsDataFrame[-1,]
    print(totalListingsDataFrame)
    return(totalListingsDataFrame)
}
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. I have seen elsewhere that others have had this issue but have not found a solution.

**UPDATE**

I tried running a smaller example of my app where I just scrape from one page on craigslist and I get the below error:

[image]

Comment: Note: I believe the issue is with the scraping because of the "data not found" error in the logs on shiny.

Comment: Elaborate on the server configuration. If the server lacks sufficient outbound privilege (port 80, 443) the request will be firewalled.

Comment: @BransonFox can you tell me a little more about what you'd like to know about the server configuration? I am using a free shiny account and all default settings for the actual server. Regarding my server function, I can provide more code for that if that's what you mean. Thanks for taking the time to respond!

Comment: I'm assuming that's shinyapps.io. I haven't used it enough to know how it handles outbound requests, but [these ips](https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/applications.html#firewalls) could be getting blocked by craigslist. To test that, I'd deploy a minimal app that just makes a single request to craigslist. If it works, you can rule out the networking problem. If it doesn't, you probably can't use shinyapps.io.

Comment: This is good advice. Thanks Branson. I will try this and will reply back here with updates.

Comment: @BransonFox I went ahead and tried a smaller example. Getting what appears to be a clearer error now. Maybe this helps?

Comment: The 403 HTTP error indicates that access is forbidden by the server for some reason. Meaning, most likely, that craigslist is blocking traffic from the shinyapps.io servers. The simple answer is that you cannot deploy your app on shinyapps.io. The complicated answer is that you could proxy your traffic from a different ip, as to not get blocked from craigslist. That's a whole different question really.

Comment: Gotcha. This is definitely a bummer, but glad to know the issue is not faulty code. Maybe I'll open my own server or deploy the app as a standalone desktop application. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: If you do want to deploy it yourself, Docker may be one of the easiest ways to achieve this. See [this post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/deploying-an-r-shiny-app-with-docker/) on R Bloggers

Comment: Very cool - thanks a lot! I'll give this a try.